# Anyone have any problems with Gparted (open source partition editor) on Windows? I.e., Is it SAFE?

Tags: windows-7, gparted

I need to repartition a HD in Windows 7 (delete a partition and then expand an adjacent partition).

I'm happy to buy software but free is always nice. I see gParted comes recommended but just wanted to check to see if anyone has had problems with it.

To quote the German Dentist in Marathon Man, "Ezzz ete Savfe?"

Comment: I used gparted last week to move my Windows 7 install from its original drive to a larger one. The only problems I had involved the master boot record on the new drive, which should be irrelevant to what you want to do. So it should work as well as anything else would. Back up the data first.

Comment: "is it safe?" You are manually editing partitions. Unless you really know what you are doing, this is not something that is exactly safe in the first place. Like @Mike said, back up!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the built in Disk Manager. Windows 7 allows for partition actions on the existing system partition including expanding it.  I expanded my system partition recently without incident.

BACKUP first!  (I didn't but you'll never forgive yourself!)

Answer (score 4):

Nothing is completely safe. Commercial software will give you the same disclaimers as `gparted` ("Back up your data. We're not responsible for what happens - If something goes wrong it's your problem, not ours.")

`gparted` is probably capable of doing what you want, but make sure to read the documentation carefully and make sure you understand it before proceeding.  Ensure you have current, verified, restorable backups.  If in doubt, don't proceed.

Comment: +1. You can't prove a negative. "I won't hurt my computer" can be supported by a million anecdotes, but it only takes one error to ruin the premise.

Answer (score 1):

Might want to take a look at [EASEUS Partition Master.](http://www.partition-tool.com/epm-unlimited.htm)

> EaseUS Partition Master Unlimited Edition is an ALL-IN-ONE partition
>   solution and reliable PC & Server disk management toolkit, especially
>   for large enterprise users. It allows unlimited usage within your
>   company.
>
> It covers all the features of EaseUS Partition Master Server Edition
>   and brings together flawless hard disk management for Windows Server
>   2000/2003/Home Server/2008(R2 SP1 included) and Windows
>   2000/XP/Vista/Windows 7(SP1 included)/Windows 8 on MBR and GUID
>   partition table (GPT) disk including: Partition Manager, Disk &
>   Partition Copy Wizard and Partition Recovery Wizard.

A little bit more expensive, but our company recently re-partitioned all of our servers. using it. Performs the repartition with out having to power off the server, then a simple re-boot is necessary to commit the changes. Doesn't take very long at all. No data loss whatsoever, however you always want to back things up.

Gparted is nice because it is free and it does work, but downtime is involved.

Comment: There is a home edition that is free for non-business use. I have used it many times, works great.
http://www.partition-tool.com/landing/home-download.htm